# Snap to grid doesn't *really* snap to grid

Tags: adobe-indesign, alignment, grids

The option "Snap to Document Grid", although it *trying* to help you to aling an object/frame correctly, doesn't prevent it to be aligned somewhat off, e.g. with X=13p6.462 instead of 13p6.

Is it possible to make it work in a more strict way, so that the object that you are trying to align (with mouse, of course) will never be aligned with such offsets?

Comment: Dont use the black arrow to move objects then you can snap some random point or object center. But if you use white arrow you can start dragging from the point you want to align. So anyway it snaps to grid just does not snap the part of the object to grid you thought it would snap.

Comment: @joojaa, just realized in the toolbar in dark themes, "black arrow" is white and "white arrow" is black. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be caused by your object not having dimensions that fit within the grid. Then it can snap in different places.

[image]

It could for example happen when you apply a stroke which is aligned to *center* or *outside*.

[image]

You also just have to accept that the grid have some *snapping tolerance*. Objects don't snap to the grid unless they are near gridlines.

You can adjust how close an object must be to a gridline or guide (on screen) before it snaps, in *Preferences > Guides & Pasteboard > Guide Options > Snap to Zone*. It can be set from 1 to 36 px.

[image]